# How should I allow others to dynamically find web services?

Tags: web-services, jboss, soa, uddi, juddi

I have been fighting with this for a while now. I need to prototype SOA, and with it, the registry. I have been fiddling with jUDDIv3 on JBoss SOA Platform 5, but there don't appear to be any tools that allow me to publish to a v3 jUDDI registry. See my related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284160/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-a-uddi-registry) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288687/how-can-i-register-the-wsdl-location-of-a-web-service-to-juddiv3-on-jboss-soa-p-5).

I realize after reading comments on those questions, and some articles on the internet (like [this one](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2005/02/uddi_30_who_really_cares.html)) that UDDI is failing or dead, however my organization has some legacy tech we need to work with.

Also, my supervisor (I'm an intern) is adamant about sticking to standards. In principle, I agree with this, but perhaps a dead standard really isn't a much of a standard if nobody uses it.

*In short, I need to provide the registry component of Service Oriented Architecture. It probably needs to be UDDI, so that it fits with the legacy tech, and satisfies the standard. Whatever the solution, it would be best if there were tools available that allow me to publish web services to that registry.*

This problem has dragged on much longer than I would have liked. Any small piece of advice is really appreciated.

Comment: "there don't appear to be any tools that allow me to publish to a v3 jUDDI registry". Care to elaborate on what exactly you need? There's a number of tools that use the UDDI spec that should work. jUDDI 3.2 has both a CLI and a web UI

Answer (score 0):

You may use WS-Discovery. WS-Discovery is a standard protocol for discovering services and service endpoints. This enables service clients to search for services based on a given criteria and bind with the discovered services. There are tow modes of WS-Discovery,

**ad-hoc** - servers advertise the services they have using a UDP multicast protocol
**managed mode** - servers and clients use an intermediary known as the discovery proxy for all service discovery purposes.

You can simply try this out with WSO2 Platform (free and open source under apache2 license). Please follow [1] to see a simple scenario of WS-Discovery in managed mode.

[1] http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2010/04/ws-discovery-with-wso2-carbon.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have heard of WS-Discovery, but I haven't done much reading. I did look at your link. How easy or hard would it be to switch client services using UDDI to using WS-Discovery?

Comment: It's totally different. There's no standardized APIs that span across protocols or implementations, unfortunately.