# Web Service Directory - UDDI?

Tags: wcf, web-services, uddi

I have been tasked with building a registry/directory of the WCF web services in my organization. My first thought was about using UDDI. However, UDDI doesn't seem to enjoy particularly good press, with some claiming it is dead - see [What are some good alternatives to a UDDI registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284160/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-a-uddi-registry)

Considering the following:

- this registry is strictly for business purposes, i.e. we want a list
  of web services and document their functionality web service
- discovery is not required, i.e. clients will continue to be
  pre-configured and any changes to any service will be manually
  propagated
- it should be possible to automate publishing to the registry, e.g. as
  part of the service deployment process

Are there are any good alternatives worth considering?

Answer (score 1):

- UDDI
- ebXML
- WS-Discovery
- mDNS

If you're in Java-land, JAXR is another location

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a custom SharePoint list.

Comment: that only works if you have sharepoint available and you're commited to a specific version, can you know where the farm is, and you know the id of the list and the columns it contains. That's a lot of things you need to know ahead of item. The point of dynamic discovery is that you need to know at least as possible to figure out where the service is.

Comment: Yeah, pity that dynamic discovery didn't become more popular. And SharePoint Foundations is free.And you only need a single URL to find the list and read the metadata _and_ the data.